# Unknown memory utilization in Ubuntu14.04 Trusty

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 on a new machine with 8GB of RAM, and it seems to be locking up periodically and nothing is in syslog file. I've installed Nagios and have been watching the graphs, and it looks like memory is going high from 7% to 72% in just a span of 10 mins. Only node process are running on server. In top I found all process are running very normal memory consumption. Even after stopping node process. Memory remains with same utilization.

free agrees, claiming I'm using more than 5.7G of memory:

## free -h

total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 7.8G 6.5G 1.3G 2.2M 233M 612M
-/+ buffers/cache: 5.7G 2.1G
Swap: 2.0G 0B 2.0G

This other formula for totaling the memory roughly agrees:

```
# ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}'
503612
```

If the processes only total 500 MiB, where's the rest of the memory going?

Answer (score 0):

I've got solution on this... so just wanna to update the same...

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

This resolved my issue. So I have added the same in my cron for every 5 mins on each of ubuntu  server